# Ruby on Rails: named Scope OR is getting translated into AND when it becomes SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
{ :conditions =>  ["#{"(visibility = #{Shared::PUBLIC}) || " if include_non_employee_public} (visibility IN (#{employee_privacy}) AND user_id IN (#{users}))"] }
```

there is my condition  for my named scope.  now i've tried both || and OR in the named scope, but the console always shows AND.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ :conditions =>  ["#{"(visibility = #{Shared::PUBLIC}) || " if include_non_employee_public} (visibility IN (#{employee_privacy}) AND user_id IN (#{users}))"] }
```

It's confusing trying to reverse engineer what you're trying to do here.  Generally though an sql query should always use "OR" rather than "||".  || will only work in your ruby code. Also, normally you should use ? and then put the value afterwards rather than use string evaluation.  That will work better with arrays for example which you seem to be using here.  Eg

```
{ :conditions =>  ["#{"(visibility = ?) || " if include_non_employee_public} (visibility IN (?) AND user_id IN (?))"], Shared::PUBLIC, employee_privacy, users]  }
```

Ok, next step is to work out what you are trying to do.  Let's say for the sake of argument that include_non_employee_public is true.  Then you will get

```
{ :conditions =>  ["(visibility = ?) || (visibility IN (?) AND user_id IN (?))"], Shared::PUBLIC, employee_privacy, users]  }
```

Let's swap that || for an or so it will work in sql:

```
{ :conditions =>  ["(visibility = ?) or (visibility IN (?) AND user_id IN (?))"], Shared::PUBLIC, employee_privacy, users]  }
```

Is that what you are trying to do?  This now won't work though because in the case where  include_non_employee_public is false, you now have a spare value (Shared::Public) in the second part of the argument list.  I would, for the sake of comprehensibility, break this into an if statement:

```
if include_non_employee_public
  conditions = ["(visibility = ?) or (visibility IN (?) AND user_id IN (?))"], Shared::PUBLIC, employee_privacy, users] 
else
  conditions = ["visibility IN (?) AND user_id IN (?)"], employee_privacy, users] 
end
```

Now you can say :conditions => conditions in your query.